# Word for a group of numbers?

Tags: wording, names, numbers, grouped-list

I have a list of different numbers/ID's related to a company and right now I am using the title ID's to group them but I feel that this title may not be the best. Does anyone know of any better words out there to group these under?

[image]

Comment: What kind of entities are you talking about here? People, products, purchases, etc.

Comment: the entities are companies

Comment: Think I was not clear in the first question. Do you mean it is a two column table? ID - Company name? Or are there more variables?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the standalone *IDs* doesn't sit well in this instance, partly perhaps because it sounds like it's impressing the system model naming onto the user model, and partly because it looks a bit short, awkward and lonely.

Developers are used to IDs for this that and the other, but in the interface that is exposed to the user, the terminology should be more contextual and immediately descriptive.

The term ID is not bad, per se, it just needs a little more context - like 'Apple ID', 'Photo ID', etc.

So either avoid the use of IDs, or at least prefix it, eg:

- Reference Numbers
- Identification Numbers
- Registration Numbers
- Company IDs

Comment: You could also opt not to abbreviate... Company ID still sounds like it is coming from the nerds' room :-)

Answer (score 1):

ID is an abbreviation, but descriptiveness is better than brevity here... how about just **"Identification"**?

Answer (score 0):

It kinda depends on your audience, but generally try to use the most semantic meaning possible.

If you are only referring to the companies by their ID's then using the title, "Company", should be acceptable. However, if you also are referring to the companies somewhere else in the UX by their name/title (i.e. "StackOverflow") then using the title, "ID", would be acceptable. One caveat would be if a company has multiple IDs (i.e. a UI displaying multiple companies each with their own set of product license Ids ), in which case you would want to qualify the title, "ID", with something more semantic.

EDIT: Looking at your example, I would preface, "ID", with a common attribute of the displayed IDs. If there are no common attributes exist, then "IDs" or "Identifiers" would be appropriate.